# Bundle not resolving while creating Mongodb OSGI Bundle using Amdatu

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, amdatu

I am creating **OSGi** bundle for **Mongodb** using `org.amdatu.mongo` service factory following [this guide](http://www.amdatu.org/components/mongodb.html) I am using **Gridfs** for the storage purpose. I am using eclipse Bndtool plugin.
for this purpose I have created an Interface Named **AgendaMongo** and an **Activator** and **Implementation** class here is code for both

```
public class Activator extends DependencyActivatorBase {

@Override
public void init(BundleContext arg0, DependencyManager manager)
        throws Exception {
    manager.add(createComponent()
            .setInterface(AgendaMongo.class.getName(), null)
            .setImplementation(Gridfs_Mongodb.class));
}
```

and the implementation

```
public class Gridfs_Mongodb implements AgendaMongo{
GridFSInputFile gfsinput=null;
private volatile MongoDBService mongoservice;
public Object store_in_db() {
    GridFSInputFile gfsinput=null;
    try {
        GridFS gfsHandler;
        gfsHandler = new GridFS(mongoservice.getDB(), "rest_data");// database
        File uri = new File("f:\\get1.jpg");                                    // name and
        gfsinput = gfsHandler.createFile(uri);
        gfsinput.saveChunks(1000);
        gfsinput.setFilename("new file");
        gfsinput.save();
        System.out.println(gfsinput.getId());
        //save_filepath("file",gfsinput.getId());
        Object get_id = gfsinput.getId();//get_filename();
        System.out.println(getData(get_id));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return gfsinput.getId();
}

/*
 * Retrieving the file
 */
public InputStream getData(Object file_id) {
    GridFS gfsPhoto = new GridFS(mongoservice.getDB(), "rest_data");
    GridFSDBFile dataOutput = gfsPhoto.findOne((ObjectId) file_id);
    DBCursor cursor = gfsPhoto.getFileList();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
    System.out.println(dataOutput);
    return dataOutput.getInputStream();

}


}
```

Now on Running and Testing it using **apache Felix Gogo** compiler I am getting the following exception.

```
! could not resolve the bundles
! Failed to start bundle agenda.mongodb.mongo_gfs-0.0.0, exception Unresolved constraint in bundle agenda.mongodb.mongo_gfs [7]: Unable to resolve 7.0: missing requirement [7.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.mongodb)(version>=2.11.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem According to **amdatu** we need mongo jar as a dependency that is required at run time for I need to add this mongo jar in requirement `osgi.wiring.package` mostly occurs due to missing dependency package.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the standard Mongo driver bundle as well: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/